# Sorting list of type string, containing email domain names

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of domain names, called [domain], that I am trying to sort alphabetically. However, the sort function is not working. I'm not sure if this is because each domain name, represented by a string in a list, contains a period?

Here is what the [domain] object output looks like:

```
['Aenean.edu', 'Aliquamfringilla.com', 'Curabiturvellectus.net', 'Curae.com', 'Duisdignissimtempor.com', 'Lorem.net', 'Maecenasiaculis.co.uk', 'Maurismolestie.co.uk', 'Namligula.edu', 'Phasellusdapibus.edu', 'Quisqueimperdiet.ca', 'Sedpharetrafelis.org', 'Suspendisse.co.uk', 'aenim.ca', 'ametrisus.com', 'anteblanditviverra.co.uk', 'arcu.org', 'arcuVestibulumante.org', 'blanditatnisi.ca', 'consectetuercursuset.org', 'consequat.co.uk', 'consequat.com', 'convallisdolor.co.uk', 'cursuset.net', 'cursusinhendrerit.edu', 'dapibus.ca', 'diamPellentesquehabitant.com', 'dictumeu.org', 'dui.co.uk', 'duinecurna.org', 'egestas.co.uk', 'egestas.net', 'egestasadui.co.uk', 'enim.org', 'erat.co.uk', 'erat.org', 'eratEtiam.net', 'eros.ca', 'est.ca', 'etlacinia.com', 'ettristiquepellentesque.ca', 'eudolor.edu', 'euultrices.co.uk', 'facilisisvitae.ca', 'fermentumarcu.edu', 'feugiat.org', 'fringilla.edu', 'inmagnaPhasellus.edu', 'interdumfeugiatSed.edu', 'ipsumprimis.com', 'laciniaorciconsectetuer.ca', 'lectusNullam.co.uk', 'liberoDonec.net', 'ligulaelitpretium.org', 'magna.com', 'magnaUt.org', 'magnis.edu', 'magnisdisparturient.co.uk', 'malesuadamalesuadaInteger.ca', 'maurisipsum.edu', 'miac.edu', 'nectellusNunc.net', 'nisi.co.uk', 'nonbibendum.edu', 'nullamagna.edu', 'nuncinterdum.edu', 'odio.ca', 'odioAliquamvulputate.edu', 'orcilobortis.net', 'orciluctus.org', 'ornare.org', 'ornarelectusjusto.net', 'pedeSuspendissedui.edu', 'placerat.ca', 'placerataugueSed.com', 'posuereat.net', 'purus.ca', 'purus.net', 'quam.net', 'quis.ca', 'risusDonec.net', 'risusaultricies.co.uk', 'rutrumnon.com', 'seddolor.org', 'sedsapien.ca', 'suscipitest.ca', 'temporaugueac.com', 'tinciduntaliquamarcu.com', 'tinciduntpedeac.com', 'tinciduntvehicularisus.org', 'tortordictumeu.org', 'ullamcorper.ca', 'ullamcorper.co.uk', 'ultrices.org', 'urnanec.net', 'ut.org', 'velesttempor.edu', 'vitae.edu', 'vitaeeratVivamus.net', 'vitaeodiosagittis.edu']
```

```
domain.sort(key=None, reverse=False)
```

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mre]:  try to condense your example to as few items as possible while still conveying your intentions. Also you say "the sort function is not working" but do not explain how it is not working. Please include what you expect to see as output.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the sorting you are performing is in lexicographic order where `a` to `z` comes before `A` to `Z`, if you want to do case insensitive sorting, you can pass `lambda` function to `key` parameter, and return either `lower` or `upper` for a given string, or just the `str.lower` function:

```py
>>> domain.sort(reverse=False, key=str.lower)
>>> domain
['Aenean.edu', 'aenim.ca', 'Aliquamfringilla.com', 'ametrisus.com', 'anteblanditviverra.co.uk', 'arcu.org', 'arcuVestibulumante.org', 'blanditatnisi.ca', 'consectetuercursuset.org', 'consequat.co.uk', 'consequat.com', 'convallisdolor.co.uk', 'Curabiturvellectus.net', 'Curae.com', 'cursuset.net', 'cursusinhendrerit.edu', 'dapibus.ca', 'diamPellentesquehabitant.com', 'dictumeu.org', 'dui.co.uk', 'duinecurna.org', 'Duisdignissimtempor.com', 'egestas.co.uk', 'egestas.net', 'egestasadui.co.uk', 'enim.org', 'erat.co.uk', 'erat.org', 'eratEtiam.net', 'eros.ca', 'est.ca', 'etlacinia.com', 'ettristiquepellentesque.ca', 'eudolor.edu', 'euultrices.co.uk', 'facilisisvitae.ca', 'fermentumarcu.edu', 'feugiat.org', 'fringilla.edu', 'inmagnaPhasellus.edu', 'interdumfeugiatSed.edu', 'ipsumprimis.com', 'laciniaorciconsectetuer.ca', 'lectusNullam.co.uk', 'liberoDonec.net', 'ligulaelitpretium.org', 'Lorem.net', 'Maecenasiaculis.co.uk', 'magna.com', 'magnaUt.org', 'magnis.edu', 'magnisdisparturient.co.uk', 'malesuadamalesuadaInteger.ca', 'maurisipsum.edu', 'Maurismolestie.co.uk', 'miac.edu', 'Namligula.edu', 'nectellusNunc.net', 'nisi.co.uk', 'nonbibendum.edu', 'nullamagna.edu', 'nuncinterdum.edu', 'odio.ca', 'odioAliquamvulputate.edu', 'orcilobortis.net', 'orciluctus.org', 'ornare.org', 'ornarelectusjusto.net', 'pedeSuspendissedui.edu', 'Phasellusdapibus.edu', 'placerat.ca', 'placerataugueSed.com', 'posuereat.net', 'purus.ca', 'purus.net', 'quam.net', 'quis.ca', 'Quisqueimperdiet.ca', 'risusaultricies.co.uk', 'risusDonec.net', 'rutrumnon.com', 'seddolor.org', 'Sedpharetrafelis.org', 'sedsapien.ca', 'suscipitest.ca', 'Suspendisse.co.uk', 'temporaugueac.com', 'tinciduntaliquamarcu.com', 'tinciduntpedeac.com', 'tinciduntvehicularisus.org', 'tortordictumeu.org', 'ullamcorper.ca', 'ullamcorper.co.uk', 'ultrices.org', 'urnanec.net', 'ut.org', 'velesttempor.edu', 'vitae.edu', 'vitaeeratVivamus.net', 'vitaeodiosagittis.edu']
```